# Pesquisando e abrindo arquivos por nome

Tags: c#, algoritmo-de-busca

Bom gostaria de um código que procurasse por todo o diretório `@"c:\"`
com um nome que eu colocar e abrisse a pasta ou pastas onde estão localizados.

Ex:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\" + PastaOndeEstaLocalizadoOArquivo);
```

Obs.: mesmo que eu escreva o nome maiúsculo ou apenas um pedaço do nome do arquivo apareça.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) passando o parâmetro `searchPattern`.

O parâmetro `searchPattern` é uma string que suporta os *wildcards* `*` (zero ou mais caracteres na posição) e `?` (zero ou um caractere na posição).

Nesse overload vai precisar do parâmetro [`searchOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx). Ele suporta os valores:

- SearchOption.AllDirectories: procura nas pastas e nas subpastas
- SearchOption.TopOnlyDirectory: procura somente na pasta do parâmetro `path`.

No exemplo abaixo, procura por todos os arquivos que comecem em um dado termo.

```
DirectoryInfo diretorioRaiz = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
string termoPesquisa = "teste";
FileInfo[] arquivosEncontrados = diretorioRaiz.GetFiles($"*${termoPesquisa}*.*", 
           SearchOption.AllDirectories) // veja o wildcard e a extensão

// agora você tem a lista com os arquivos, manipule-os da maneira que preferir
```

Arquivos e pastas são *case sensitive* no Windows. `C:\Pasta\Arquivo.exe` se refere ao mesmo que `c:\pasta\arquivo.exe` ou `C:\PASTA\ARQUIVO.EXE`.

De qualquer forma vale a pena [**ler a documentação**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método `GetFiles` da classe `Directory`, que retorna um array de strings com o nome de cada arquivo encontrado.

Você só precisa informar a pasta onde vai ser realizar a busca, no seu caso, `C:\\`
;

O filtro para pesquisa, no seu caso o nome do arquivo;

E a opção de busca, no seu caso, `AllDirectories` para buscar em todas as sub-pastas.

Segue o código:

```
string arquivo = "arquivo.txt";

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", arquivo, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    Process.Start(file); //abre o arquivo
    Process.Start(new FileInfo(file).DirectoryName);//abre a pasta do arquivo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o DirectoryInfo, a depender da versão do windows você pode fazer uma varredura completa do seu disco fazendo a busca com "C:\.*"